# Convert MATLAB objects to struct?

Tags: matlab, object, struct

Our software, lets call it **Mine**, relies on another simulation software, lets call it **Sim**. Unfortunately, there is a bug in **Sim**.

In order to aide in the debugging process for **Sim**, I need to supply the simulation file and the inputs for it.

This would mean passing **Mine's** MATLAB objects and their classes. Unfortunately, these classes are confidential material. So is there a way, I could down-cast(?) or convert the objects back to structs? This would provide the input values for the **Sim** but would not reveal to the owners of **Sim** how these values are derived.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The `struct` function can convert objects to struct.

```
 struct(obj)
```

Comment: That doesn't convert the nested objects e.g. `obj.obj`

Comment: I have had to write a DFS type algorithm for converting nested objects to nested structs before. It may sound fancy but is actually pretty easy to write.

Comment: For any cycles in your object structure, a conversion to struct is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand your use case, but I needed to do something similar. I control an experiment through Matlab. Each device is controlled via an object (instance of some custom class). The state of each device is stored in public properties of its object. I occasionally want to save the state of my equipment, which means I have to loop over all public properties, recursively, and put all data into a struct.

Maybe the code best speaks for itself.

```
function output_struct = obj2struct(obj)
% Converts obj into a struct by examining the public properties of obj. If
% a property contains another object, this function recursively calls
% itself on that object. Else, it copies the property and its value to 
% output_struct. This function treats structs the same as objects.
%
% Note: This function skips over serial, visa and tcpip objects, which
% contain lots of information that is unnecessary (for us).

properties = fieldnames(obj); % works on structs & classes (public properties)
for i = 1:length(properties)
    val = obj.(properties{i});
    if ~isstruct(val) && ~isobject(val)
        output_struct.(properties{i}) = val; 
    else
        if isa(val, 'serial') || isa(val, 'visa') || isa(val, 'tcpip')
            % don't convert communication objects
            continue
        end
        temp = obj2struct(val);
        if ~isempty(temp)
            output_struct.(properties{i}) = temp;
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Sorry, I had renamed the function from `trap2struct`(our internal name) to `obj2struct` when I posted it here and forgot to update the name in the recursive call. I fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

That's how I translate object into a structure and save it as `a(count) = output_struct;`. Here there is iteration on nested objects and saving empty fields.

```
function output_struct = object2struct(obj)
output_struct = struct();

properties = fieldnames(obj);
for i = 1:length(properties)
    propname = properties{i};
    propval = obj.(propname);
    if ~isempty(propval)
        for j = 1:length(propval)
            val = propval(j);
            if ~isstruct(val) && ~isobject(val) || isdatetime(val)
                output_struct.(propname)(j) = val; 
            else
                output_struct.(propname)(j) = object2struct(val); 
            end
        end
    else
        output_struct.(propname) = [];
    end
end
```